# Why PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY does not remove empty lines

Tags: php

```
<?php
 $block = <<<EOF

       attract    new                           clients
       wish you the best of success



       boost sales words

EOF;

    $block = preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $block);
    $block = preg_replace("/\v+/", '\n',$block);
    $arr = preg_split("/\R+/", $block, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($arr);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  attract new clients
    [1] =>  wish you the best of success
    [2] =>
    [3] =>  boost sales words
    [4] =>
)
```

As per [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) only non empty pieces will be returned.

Comment: It does, https://3v4l.org/11QDP. Provided result is not the result.

Comment: No I've checked on two different Ubuntu with PHP versions 5.3.10  and PHP7 it isn't so. If I copy code from here to my terminal then yes it works but from Netbeans(Win10) to terminal - No

Comment: Perhaps the `\n` should be `PHP_EOL` for windows system? The issue is not as described, `preg_split_no_empty` works as intended. The issue you are having is more specific so you should update the question with more details.